# How to test services that use Hibernate Search?

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, lucene, hibernate-search

I have JUnit4 test class, **annotated with `@Transactional`** with this method in it, along with other methods:

```
@Test
public void testDiscoverArtworksByTitle()
{
    FullTextEntityManager ftem = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);

    this.prepareArtworksForListing();
    ftem.flushToIndexes();

    List<ArtworkListItem> listItems = this.artworkService.discoverArtworksByTitle("Die Hard");
    Assert.assertNotEquals("There are some items in the list", 0, listItems.size());

    // housekeeping
    ftem.purgeAll(ArtworkEntity.class);
}
```

Basically, I'm building some discovery functionality and I would like to test it properly while developing and mainly later.
The point is, this test always fails, as if the index was not built at all.
The method `prepareArtworksForListing()` creates (using `persist(..)`) some records in `HSqlDb` in-memory database. Hibernate is wired with H.Search/Lucene properly, because when I annotate this method with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` and explicitly call `em.getTransaction().begin()` and `em.getTransaction().commit()/.rollback()`, the test is passed, BUT THEN subsequent test methods fail with `READ_ONLY TX Error`, as if the original `@Transactional` attribute was absent for the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a solution and I've realized, how does Lucene/Hibernate Search works in connection with auto-updating indexes. The indexes are updated (internally) on transaction commit, but not directly, but on `flush()`. Therefore, calling `flush()` on `EntityManager` does the trick while keeping `@Transactional` intact for the class.

So the code should look something like this (I've added some exception handling as well):

```
@Test
public void testDiscoverArtworksByTitle()
{
    FullTextEntityManager ftem = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);

    this.prepareArtworksForListing();
    this.entityManager.flush(); // <-- ADDED FLUSH() CALL
    ftem.flushToIndexes();

    try
    {
        List<ArtworkListItem> listItems = this.artworkService.discoverArtworksByTitle("Die Hard");
        Assert.assertNotEquals("There are some items in the list", 0, listItems.size());
    }
    finally
    {
        // housekeeping
        ftem.purgeAll(ArtworkEntity.class);
    }
}
```